# How to read data in specific row in an excel file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to read data in specific row and print it using Apache POI.
Example: 
I want to print row = 4 in an excel file and row # will keep changing.

```
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    rowData = new ArrayList<>();

    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        System.out.println("Col Index = "+cell.getColumnIndex());
        System.out.println("Col Index = "+cell.getStringCellValue());

    }
```

I tried above code and it is giving me 1st row in excel but I want specific row from excel.

Comment: What concrete problem do you have using [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) or [CellUtil.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html#getRow-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet-)?

Comment: Added sample code I tried.

Comment: what do you mean with "row # will keep changing"?

Comment: It means
Depending on the scenario, user will change the row number to be retrieved and printed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(4);

Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()){
    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
    System.out.println("Col Index = "+cell.getColumnIndex());
    System.out.println("Col Index = "+cell.getStringCellValue());

}
```